# Using batch file for running SQL Server Express with parameter silently

Tags: batch-file, sql-server-2008r2-express

I use this code for running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Express in silent mode but this program exit with error

```
@echo off
set DIRPATH=%~dp0%Sql Express 2008 R2
set Auth=""NT Authority\SYSTEM""
if exist "%DIRPATH%" goto installProg
echo file not found

goto end

:installProg 

start "Running Rahbordi App" "%DIRPATH%\SQLEXPR_x86_ENU" "/QS /HIDECONSOLE /ACTION=Install /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESSR2 /SQLSVCACCOUNT=%Auth% /AddCurrentUserAsSQLAdmin"

:end
```

Error:

> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> The argument '/QS /HIDECONSOLE /ACTION=INSTALL /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESSR2 /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN' is formatted incorrectly.
>   The delimiter '=' is missing.
>
> Error code 0x84B40006.

I don't know that why this error happen. Many thanks for any help.

Edit: ]n detail of error i just say that after **NT** an enter character printed.

Comment: Try prefixing each `=` in the `start` line with a caret thus: `^=`. I'm not sure this will help, but it won't hurt. Another possibility is to simply delete the `start "Running Rahbordi App"` since the batch simply apparently termiantes after the `start` - you could set `title` before  executing sqlexpr... but it may depend on your context.

Comment: I hope `/ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=TRUE` could help.

Comment: thanks [@JosefZ](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) but this not work

Comment: I hope space between **NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM** cause this error.
I don't know how can set it to bat file!!